# Using Raspberry Pi as an SVN server?

Tags: raspbian, server, software-development, software-recommendation

I am a software developer (mainly [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) and [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)), and I need to handle my work using a [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) (SVN) system.

So I am thinking that I can install the **SVN server** on Raspbian (I do not have too much space at home, and I can always keep it turned on, consuming little electricity).

I have found many tutorials to do this online, but my question is: How does it work? Is performance acceptable? At this time it only has to handle one developer (only me, I need it to version my work) and in the future I think no more than three developers.

Is there a smart solution or a tutorial that I can find online?

Comment: Out of the blue I'd suggest: yes, it would work. The question whether the performance is acceptable or not, however is highly subjective. Have a look at: https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-how-to-svn-server/ stating "It’s not incredibly practical but it seems to work well for me, as I’m the only developer using it." Perhaps you could add some more information to your question, such as what amount of data you intend to check out each day.

Comment: Word of warning: if your disk fails you will lose your work... I think it would be wise to use a free cloud based svn/git/...

Comment: After all SVN is no back-up system per se. Backing your files and/or the repository up to a secondary system is of course a mandatory measure.

Answer (score 3):

`svn+ssh` will likely perform a good deal better than using [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) + mod_svn (i.e. [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)) as there's simply less that the Raspberry Pi needs to do to handle the requests. You'll probably also find that the whole thing will be more reliable and faster if you keep the repository on a hard disk rather than the SD card. If you do keep it on the SD card then you'll want to be backing it up every day or two at least.

So long as your project isn't too big (up to a few hundreds of files rather than tens of thousands of files) it will probably be OK, but if you think it is too slow then consider something like [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) which will be much faster.

Comment: agree on using HDD, not SD for the SVN storage

Answer (score 3):

I've been using SVN and WebSVN for more than two years with a (old version 256 MB RAM) Raspberry Pi in my local network, and it worked OK for me - I liked the setup guide *[Setup a Subversion Server in 4 Minutes](http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/)*.

[Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) on Raspberry Pi is faster with compression turned off. I can recommend gitosis to administer project users, gitweb, and from GitHub, git-pretty-stats.